# VB code combo dropdown on Excel 365 worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

VB combo dropdown on Excel 365 worksheet. In this combo dropdown I have connected 2 Wheelers and 4 Wheelers. When i select 4 wheelers in the combo dropdown immediately row numbers 5 to 7 need to hide, if i select 2 wheelers in the combo dropdown immediately row numbers 9 to 11 need to hide.

Her Only VB Combo box related. Need not to use data validation dropdowns. How to over come my issue...

Comment: Please use a vba tag and remove the vb6 one as your question asks about vba code within Excel, not from an external VB6 application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a Combo Box:

---

Click on the Developer tab (if it’s not visible, go to **File > Options > Customize Ribbon**, check the Developer box, and click OK).
Under Form Controls, click Combo box (Form Control) or under ActiveX Controls, click Combo Box (ActiveX Control).

2. Link the Combo Box to Your Data:

---

Click on the cell where you want to insert the combo box.
Drag the cursor to create the combo box.
Now link the combo box to the range containing your list of options (in this case, “2 Wheelers” and “4 Wheelers”). This will populate the combo box with these choices.

3. Write VBA Code:

---

Press Alt + F11 to open the Visual Basic for Applications editor.
In the Project Explorer, find your worksheet and double-click it.
In the code window, write the following VBA code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim selectedValue As String
    selectedValue = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Rows("5:7").EntireRow.Hidden = (selectedValue = "4 Wheelers")
    Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = (selectedValue = "2 Wheelers")
End Sub
```

4. Assign the Macro:

---

Close the VBA editor.
Right-click the combo box and choose Properties.
In the LinkedCell property, enter a cell reference (e.g., A1).

Go to the Developer tab, click Insert, and choose Button (Form Control).
Draw a button on your worksheet.
Right-click the button, choose Assign Macro, and select the macro you just created.

Now, when you select “4 Wheelers” or “2 Wheelers” from the combo box, the specified rows will be hidden accordingly.

Comment: You forgot to make the rows visible again. Instead of the If-statements, use for example `Rows("5:7").EntireRow.Hidden = (selectedValue = "4 Wheelers")`

Comment: You are right Thomas, i edit my answer